# Boost Asio: broken pipe when trying to call a write function "externaly"

Tags: c++, api, boost, boost-asio, handler

I am trying to implement a simple client - server application, in which I will introduce a simple API for the client in order to interact with the server. The problem is, that when I try to use that API the client complaints about an `system:32` error, which stands for broken pipe. However, if I call the function from inside the class everything works flawlessly.

```
    #include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <cstdio> /* sprintf */

#include "client.hpp"
#include "commands.hpp"

Client::Client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, 
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator):
    io_service_(io_service),
    socket_(io_service)
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *endpoint_iterator;
    socket_.async_connect(endpoint,
        boost::bind(&Client::handle_connect, this, endpoint_iterator, 
            boost::asio::placeholders::error
        )
    );
}

void Client::handle_connect(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator 
    endpoint_iterator, const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if(!error)
    {
        //Client::read_header(read_.header(), read_.header_length());
        Client::identify_user("User", "Password");
    }
    else if(endpoint_iterator != boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator())
    {
        socket_.close();
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *endpoint_iterator;
        socket_.async_connect(endpoint, 
            boost::bind(&Client::handle_connect, this, ++endpoint_iterator,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error
            )
        );
    }
}

void Client::handle_readheader(size_t bytes_transferred, 
    const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if(bytes_transferred)
    {
        if(read_.decode_command() == IDENTIFY)
        {
            Client::identify_user("Username", "Password");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Client::read_header(read_.header(), read_.header_length());
    }
}

void Client::handle_read(size_t bytes_transferred, 
    const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if(bytes_transferred)
    {
        Client::read_header(read_.header(), read_.header_length());
    }
    else if(error)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        Client::read_header(read_.header(), read_.header_length());
    }
}

void Client::handle_write(size_t bytes_transferred, 
    const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if(bytes_transferred)
    {
        Client::read_header(read_.header(), read_.header_length());
    }
    else if(error)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        Client::read_header(read_.header(), read_.header_length());
    }
}


void Client::handle_writeheader(size_t bytes_transferred, 
    const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if(bytes_transferred)
    {
        if(write_.decode_command() == AUTHENTICATE)
        {
            std::cout << "Bodylen:" << write_.decode_size() << std::endl;
            std::cout << write_.body() << std::endl;
            Client::write(write_.body(), write_.decode_size());
        }
    }
    else if(error)
    {
        std::cout << "Error HWH: " << error << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        Client::read_header(read_.header(), read_.header_length());
    }
}

void Client::identify_user(const char* username, const char* password)
{
    size_t tmplen = (strlen(username) + strlen(password) + 2);
    char tmpbody[tmplen];
    std::sprintf(tmpbody, "%s:%s", username, password);
    write_.body(tmpbody);
    std::cout << write_.body() << std::endl;
    write_.encode_header(11, tmplen);

    std::cout << write_.header() << std::endl;
    Client::write_header(write_.header(), write_.header_length());
}

void Client::read(char* buffer, size_t len)
{
    boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(buffer, len),
        boost::bind(&Client::handle_read, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error
        )
    );
}

void Client::read_header(char* buffer, size_t len)
{
    boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(buffer, len),
        boost::bind(&Client::handle_readheader, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error
        )
    );
}

void Client::write_header(char* buffer, size_t len)
{
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(buffer, len),
        boost::bind(&Client::handle_writeheader, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error
        )
    );
}

void Client::write(char* buffer, size_t len)
{
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(buffer, len),
        boost::bind(&Client::handle_write, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error
        )
    );
}

int main(){
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query("localhost", "5000");
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    Client client(io_service, iterator);

    //client.identify_user("User", "Password");

    io_service.run();

    return(0);
}
```

In theory, the behaviour should be the following: the client sends an authentication header to the server —*through identify_client*—, indicating the number of bytes to be sent afterwards, and waits until it receives an ACK —*calling read_header(...)*—. The servers sends an ACK confirming that is ready to process whatever the client sends. The client sends the user and the password.

However, as I said above, it only seems to work when I call `identify_client` through the `handle_connect`, something which is completely useless and static. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance.

---

**EDIT:** The message class is just a class very similar to [this one](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/chat/chat_message.hpp) that helps me manipulating and easily interpreting the protocol's messages.

---

**EDIT2:** I will try to explain it a little bit better. I consider the `main` function "outside the class", as something independent. That `main` function then creates a `Client` object, that contains the API to send and receive data from the server —I attach the *.hpp* file hoping that this will help you understand better—.

Therefore, if I had a loop like the following one...

```
        /* ... */

    for(;;)
    {
        /* ... */

        // Do something here

        /* If a condition, then authenticate the user */
        //client.identify_user("User", "Password");

        // Do something there

        /* ... */
    }

    /* ... */
```

... using that created object I should be able to call specific member functions of the object, which would trigger further writes or reads. The problem I have right now, is that I can't achieve that.

If I call `identify_user` from the `handle_connect(...)` function of the `Client` class —as shown in the original code above— it works. But of course, I can't achieve what I want.

If I comment this in order to call the function from the `main`, then I get the broken pipe error.

```
    if(!error)
{
    //Client::read_header(read_.header(), read_.header_length());
    //Client::identify_user("User", "Password");
}
```

If I leave the code like this, I get the same broken pipe error.

```
if(!error)
{
    Client::read_header(read_.header(), read_.header_length());
    //Client::identify_user("User", "Password");
}
```

When I was learning about asio, I read that if the io_service runs out of work then the application finishes. Maybe my problem has something to do with that.

---

**EDIT4:** I love saying that I am going to attach something and then completely forget about it.

```
    #ifndef CLIENT_HPP
#define CLIENT_HPP

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include "message.hpp"

class Client
{
public:
    Client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, 
           boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator);

    void identify_user(const char* username, const char* password);

private:
    void handle_connect(
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator,
        const boost::system::error_code& error);
    void handle_read(size_t bytes_transferred, 
        const boost::system::error_code& error);
    void handle_readheader(size_t bytes_transferred, 
        const boost::system::error_code& error);
    void handle_write(size_t bytes_transferred,
        const boost::system::error_code& error);
    void handle_writeheader(size_t bytes_transferred,
        const boost::system::error_code& error);

    void read(char* buffer, size_t len);
    void read_header(char* buffer, size_t len);
    void write_header(char* buffer, size_t len);
    void write(char* buffer, size_t len);

    boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;

    Message read_;
    Message write_;
};

#endif /* client.hpp */
```

---

**Edit5**: This seems to do the trick. It had DEFINITELY something to do with the io_service:

```
for(;;)
{
    io_service.poll();
client.identify_user("User", "Password");
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'from inside the class'. All this code executes from inside the class.

Comment: @EJP I added some information, but maybe I am just making it more difficult to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending data over a connection which has already been closed by the peer.

It isn't clear why you would want to authenticate the client at any other time than immediately after establishing the connection.

Comment: Thanks for answering. What you say is true, however imagine that in front of this you have a GUI, and you want to trigger for some reason "identify_client", or some other function. Seeing what happens when I try to call " identify_client" I guess I would face the same problem with any other function. So, is it possible to trigger specific functions outside the class?

Comment: Of course it is possible, but if the peer has disconnected you will get broken pipe errors. What you have here is an application protocol error. Either the peer shouldn't have disconnected yet or you shouldn't be sending, or you should have created a new connection.

Comment: Excuse me, maybe I explained it wrong: you see how I have commented the "Client::read_header(...)" line inside the "handle_connect(...)" function? If I uncomment that line and comment the following one —Client::Identify_user(...)— in that exact moment is when I get the pipe error, if I try to call the function from the main. BTW I'm giving your answer as the valid one, as essentially you answered my questions. I'll review the code. Thank you very much indeed for your time. EDIT: Probably it's because I leave empty the "if (!error)" part, and therefore the io_service runs out of work and stops.